# Proper way to access array members as a different type?

Tags: c, arrays, casting, unions

I have a large array of `uint16_t`.

Most of its members are `uint16_t`, but some are `int16_t` and some `uint8_t`.

How would you handle that?

---

By the way, I tried:

1. Pointers:

   Used 2 pointers, one `int16_t*` and the other `uint8_t*`, both initialized to the start of the array, to access member of the array that are `int16_t` and `uint8_t`.

   (That worked initially, but I ran into problems when later in the program something else changed the value of the pointers, so I don't trust it.)
2. Type definition with a union.

   In file.h:

   ```
   typedef union {
     uint16_t  u16[NO_OF_WORDS];     // As uint16_t
     int16_t   s16[NO_OF_WORDS];     // As int16_t
     uint8_t   u8[2 * NO_OF_WORDS];  // As uint8_t
   } ram_params_t;
   extern ram_params_t ram_params[];
   ```

   In file.c:

   ```
   ram_params_t ram_params[] = {0};
   ```

   (That really bombed.)
3. Casting.

   (I didn't get very far with that.)

Comment: How do you know which elements are of which types? And can you show us the casting attempt? It seems the most sensible approach if they really have to be a single array.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not just have a couple of variables of the other types?  This seems very error-prone, and unmaintainable?

Comment: > Why are you doing this?           -- because the Array (which is in an Embedded system) is shared with the outside world. The external system has access to that array and only to that array. And the data are of various types.

Comment: > How do you know which elements are of which types? -- By the index. I know that member at index 3 is an int16_t, and that member at index 5 is a pair of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your attempt #2 was that you made an array of arrays.

Either do this:

```
typedef union {
  uint16_t  u16;     // As uint16_t
  int16_t   s16;     // As int16_t
  uint8_t   u8[2];   // As uint8_t
} ram_params_t;
extern ram_params_t ram_params[NO_OF_WORDS];

ram_params_t ram_params[NO_OF_WORDS];

uval16  = ram_params[i].u16;
sval16  = ram_params[i].s16;
uval8_1 = ram_params[i].u8[0];
uval8_2 = ram_params[i].u8[1];
```

Or you do this:

```
typedef union {
  uint16_t  u16[NO_OF_WORDS];     // As uint16_t
  int16_t   s16[NO_OF_WORDS];     // As int16_t
  uint8_t   u8[2 * NO_OF_WORDS];  // As uint8_t
} ram_params_t;
extern ram_params_t ram_params;

ram_params_t ram_params;

uval16  = ram_params.u16[i];
sval16  = ram_params.s16[i];
uval8_1 = ram_params.u8[2*i];
uval8_2 = ram_params.u8[2*i+1];
```

I don't see anything wrong with your attempt #1 either.  I think that I would probably do that rather than using a union.

Comment: > I don't see anything wrong with your attempt #1 -- I didn't either until today, when the value in one of the pointers changed, corrupting the data in the array. The pointer gets set once at start-up. How can I be sure that it will still set correctly after a year of running without a reset? It's just not reliable. I would have to check it's value periodically, I guess.

Comment: Your pointer getting corrupted is a sign that something else in your program is wrong and is trashing memory.  I would actually advise you to retry #1 and debug your program, otherwise you will probably end up with a different mysterious failure down the road.

Comment: > Your pointer getting corrupted is a sign that something else in your program is wrong and is trashing memory. -- Yes, absolutely! I found it and fixed it. But that was a wake-up call on the danger of relying on the pointer.

Comment: "We should be careful to get out of an experience only the wisdom that is in it and stop there lest we be like the cat that sits down on a hot stove lid. She will never sit down on a hot stove lid again and that is well but also she will never sit down on a cold one anymore." - Mark Twain

Comment: "Experience enables you to recognize a mistake when you make it again."

Franklin P. Jones

Comment: I implemented you 1st suggestion. Not only does it work well, but making byte variables as a arrays of 2 items has really cleaned up my code. I love it!

Comment: @ JS1: Please see a followup to this question and your answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999975/array-doubles-in-size-if-a-struct-defines-both-its-uint16-t-words-and-uint8-t-by

Comment: @Davide Andrea: Interesting. The compiler I use doesn't behave that way.  I guess you have to work around your compiler's strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The array elements of other types must be the same size as the `uint16_t` so just cast them. In the case of the 8-bit data, there is a possibility that the upper 8 bits are undefined, so I masked them off.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uint16_t    unsigned short
#define int16_t     short
#define uint8_t     unsigned char

int main() {
    uint16_t n;

    // convert uint16_t to int16_t
    n = 0xFFFF;
    printf ("%d\n", (int16_t)n);

    // convert uint16_t to uint8_t
    n = 168;
    printf ("%c\n", (uint8_t)(n & 0xFF));

    return 0;
}
```

Program output is

```
-1
¿
```